# Javascript reduce() - why is this returning false?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Basically, I want to evaluate all items in an array. If every item is of equal type AND value (strict equality check) return true, otherwise return false.
What am I missing here? - Thanks!

```js
function equalityChecker(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    if (prev !== curr) {
      return false;
    } 
    if (prev === curr) {
      return true;
    }
  });
}

console.log(equalityChecker([0,0,0,0,0,0])); //returns false
console.log(equalityChecker([1,1,1,1,1,1])); //returns false
```

Comment: does false === 1? does true === 1?

Comment: why reduce? and not `every`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) returns a value, and you return the result of a comparison.

In the next iteration, you use this boolean value and checks againsta value from the array.

Hint 1: Reduce does not work for this approach.

The other disadvantage is the iteration length, it loops for all elements despite of a `false` result.

Hint 2: You need a method which returns early.

Result: Take [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and compare each element with the first item.

```js
function equalityChecker(array) {
    return array.every((value, _, [first]) => first === value);
}

console.log(equalityChecker([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])); //  true
console.log(equalityChecker([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])); //  true
console.log(equalityChecker([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` compares the **result of the previous test** with the **current index**.

It doesn't compare the previous index with the current index.

(The exception is if you don't pass a value as the second argument to `reduce`, in which case the *first* comparison is between the first two indexes).

The first test compares `0` and `0` so the second test compares `true` and `0`, so the third test compares `false` and `false` and so on.

---

When you [debugged](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) this you should have added logging which would have shown you what was going on.

```js
function equalityChecker(arr) {
  console.log(arr);
  return arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    console.log(`prev: ${prev}, curr: ${curr}`);
    if (prev !== curr) {
      return false;
    }
    if (prev === curr) {
      return true;
    }
  });
}

console.log(equalityChecker([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])); //returns false
console.log(equalityChecker([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])); //returns false
```

Comment: ahhh so 'prev 'turns to 'true' after the first iteration...
So what would be the way to do this?

Comment: "*what's the way to do this*" - as noted in the comments: use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)